# Cycle through string

Tags: python, iteration, modulo

I need to be able to cycle through a string of characters using the modulo operator so that each character can be passed to a function. This is a simple question, I know, but I am seriously confused as to how to do it. Here is what I have but it gives me the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
key = 'abc'
def encrypt(key,string):
    c = ''
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        t = (key)%3
        a = XOR(ord(string[i]),ord(t))
        b = chr(a)
        c = c + b
    return(c)
```

Comment: What do you expect from `'abc' % 3` ?

Comment: I want it to separate each character in the string to that they can be passed to ord(t) in x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ingredients

Here are some ingredients which help you write your `encrypt` function in a concise way:

1. You can directly iterate over the characters of a string:

   ```
   >>> my_string = 'hello'
   >>> for c in my_string:
   ...     print(c)
   ...
   h
   e
   l
   l
   o
   ```
2. You can cycle through any iterable (like, for example, a string) using the `cycle` function from the `itertools` module of the standard library:

   ```
   >>> from itertools import cycle
   >>> for x in cycle('abc'):
   ...     print(x)
   ...
   a
   b
   c
   a
   b
   c
   a
   # goes on infinitely, abort with Ctrl-C
   ```
3. You can use the `zip` function to iterate over two sequences at the same time:

   ```
   >>> for a, b in zip('hello', 'world'):
   ...     print(a, b)
   ...
   h w
   e o
   l r
   l l
   o d
   ```

   ***Edit**: as kichik suggests, you can also use `itertools.izip` which is beneficial if you deal with very large input strings.*
4. You calculate the `xor` of two numbers by using the `^` operator:

   ```
   >>> 5 ^ 3
   6
   ```
5. You can concatenate a sequence of individual strings to a single string using the `join` function:

   ```
   >>> ''.join(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
   'hellohowareyou'
   ```
6. You can feed `join` with a so-called *generator expression*, which is similar to a `for` loop, but as a single expression:

   ```
   >>> ''.join(str(x+5) for x in range(3))
   '567'
   ```

## Putting it all together

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

def encrypt(key, string):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(k) ^ ord(c))
                   for k, c in izip(cycle(key), string))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (probably should) iterate over the characters without using range() and you'll want to run ord() on each character before you run mod on it, as the % operator means something else for a string. This should work:

```
key = 'abc'
for c in key:
    print XOR(ord(c), ord(c) % 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.cycle()` to cycle through the key and `itertools.izip()` for an easy combination of the two.

```
import itertools

def encrypt(key, string):
  keyi = itertools.cycle(key)
  result = ''
  for k, v in itertools.izip(keyi, string):
    a = ord(v) ^ ord(k)
    result += chr(a)
  return result
```

And then use it like this:

```
>>> encrypt('\x00', 'abc')
'abc'
>>> encrypt('\x01', 'abc')
'`cb'
```

You got an error about formatting because <kbd>%</kbd> is not a modulo operator for strings. It's used for formatting strings. You probably meant to use something like this:

```
key[i%3]
```

Comment: @BioGeek, his sentence is not incorrect. In the question, `key` is not an integer so `%` is of course used for formatting strings.

Comment: Indeed. I've deleted my comment.